# How do I fix this code smell in a better way?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How would you identify and fix the following code smell with a long Duplicate Methods? Here is the code-smell below:

**Code Smell**

```
    class TransactionProcessingService
      def initialize(user, product_id)
        @user    = user
        @product = Actions::Base.find_by id: product_id
      end

      def call
        return false unless valid?

        ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
          @reservation = @user.reservations.
              where(action_id: @product.id).
              where("status IS NOT NULL AND status NOT IN ('archived', 'cancelled')").
              first_or_initialize
          @reservation.update(quantity: (@reservation.quantity.presence || 0) + 1) # Nil guard

          update_state!
        end
      end

      protected

      def valid?
        @product.allowed_for?(@user) and @user.balance >= @product.price
      end

      def update_state!
        if @product.is_a?(Actions::Target)
          @user.transactions.create(status: 'sold_target', transaction_type: :product_purchase, amount: @product.price, product: @product)
          @user.update_columns(balance: @user.balance - @product.price - @product.discount_for_user(@user))
        elsif @product.is_a?(Actions::Lease)
          @user.transactions.create(status: 'sold_lease', transaction_type: :product_purchase, amount: @product.price, product: @product)
          @user.update_columns balance: @user.balance - @product.price
        end
      end
    end
```

However, I tried refactoring this but **I feel I made it worse**. How best do you think I should go about refactoring the code above? Here is what I have done bellow:

**here is what I have done...**

```
class TransactionProcessingService
  def initialize(user, product_id)
    @user    = user
    @product = Actions::Base.find_by id: product_id
  end

  def call
    false unless valid?

    ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
      update_user_reservations
      create_state
      update_balance
    end
  end

  protected

  def valid?
    @product.allowed_for?(@user) && (@user.balance >= @product.price)
  end

  def wrapper_around(*)
    @product.is_a?
  end

  def update_user_reservations
    result = @user.reservations
                       .where(action_id: @product.id)
                       .where("status IS NOT NULL AND status NOT IN ('archived', 'cancelled')").first_or_initialize
    result.update(quantity: (quantity.presence || 0) + 1)
  end

  def update_balance
    value = @user.balance - @product.price
    target = wrapper_around(Actions::Target)
    lease = wrapper_around(Actions::Lease)
    @user.update_columns(if target
                           { balance: value - @product.discount_for_user(@user) }
                         elsif lease
                           { balance: value }
                         end)
  end

  def create_state
    product_price = @product.price
    target = wrapper_around(Actions::Target)
    lease = wrapper_around(Actions::Lease)
    @user.transactions.create(if target
                                {
                                  status: 'sold_target',
                                  transaction_type: :product_purchase,
                                  amount: product_price,
                                  product: product_params
                                }
                              elsif lease
                                {
                                  status: 'sold_lease',
                                  transaction_type: :product_purchase,
                                  amount: product_price,
                                  product: product_params
                                }
                              end)
  end
end
```

Comment: Why would someone mark this down and flag it closed because he/she thinks `Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.` ? I suppose there will be other things to learn from responses despite it is opinion based ?

Comment: Try posting in [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) site, it is a much better fit for this type of questions.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3):

Just to give you an idea, you can separate the different actions you can recognize in your code with some other classes:

TransactionProcessing:

```
class TransactionProcessing
  def initialize(product_id:, user:)
    @user = user
    @product_id = product_id
  end

  def call
    return unless product
    return unless valid?

    ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
      UpdateReservation.new(product: product, user: user).update

      update_state!
    end
  end

  private

  attr_reader :product_id, :user

  delegate :id, :price, to: :product
  delegate :quantity, to: :reservation
  delegate :balance, :reservations, :transactions, to: :user

  def product
    Actions::Base.find_by(id: product_id)
  end

  def update_state!
    Object.const_get("#{product.class}Transaction").new(product: product, user: user).update
  end

  def valid?
    product.allowed_for?(user) && balance >= price
  end
end
```

UpdateReservation:

```
class UpdateReservation
  def initialize(user:, product:)
    @product = product
    @user = user
  end

  def update
    reservation.update(quantity: reservation_quantity)
  end

  private

  attr_reader :user

  delegate :id, to: :product
  delegate :reservations, to: :user
  delegate :quantity, to: :reservation

  def reservation
    reservations.where(action_id: id).where.not(status: nil)
                 where('status NOT IN ("archived", "cancelled")').first_or_initialize
  end

  def reservation_quantity
    (quantity.presence || 0) + 1 # Just if quantity.presence can be nil. Otherwise add a rescue.
  end
end
```

Actions module:

```
module Actions
  class CustomTransaction
    attr_reader :product, :user

    delegate :price, to: :product
    delegate :balance, :transactions, to: :user

    def initialize(product:, user:)
      @product = product
      @user = user
    end

    def update
      create_transaction
      update_balance
    end

    def create_transaction
      transactions.create(params)
    end

    def update_balance
      user.update(balance: balance_value)
    end

    private

    def params
      { transaction_type: :product_purchase, amount: price, product: product }
    end
  end

  class LeaseTransaction < CustomTransaction
    STATUS = 'sold_lease'.freeze
    private_constant :STATUS

    private

    def params
      super.merge(status: STATUS)
    end

    def balance_value
      balance - price - discount_for_user
    end

    def discount_for_user
      product.discount_for_user(user)
    end
  end

  class TargetTransaction < CustomTransaction
    STATUS = 'sold_target'.freeze
    private_constant :STATUS

    private

    def params
      super.merge(status: STATUS)
    end

    def balance_value
      balance - price
    end
  end
end
```

There you can see:

- The class, being under a service namespace or folder, is already a service, no need to make it redundant.
- Use the `product_id` in the initializer, avoid adding more code. `product` belongs to a separate private method.
- Give to your classes the less charge possible.
- Delegate methods to your accessors and others when possible.
- If there's shared behavior, there's always the possibility to use inheritance.
- Give to your methods the less charge possible.
- Avoid `is_a?` if you can. Just call.

Even this needs to be improved, so, anybody, feel free.

Comment: Impressing. This is cool and I love how it's so Modular